# Have these ski bindings been mounted properly?

Tags: skiing, ski-bindings

These are the first skis I've ever bought for my son. I'm not sure if the bindings have been mounted properly? It looks as though the screws may have been drilled in too deep? It's the same on the other end as well.

Would this affect skiing? durability? etc?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site! It's nice to meet you! I put your text above the pictures. You didn't do anything wrong, I just find it easier to see the words if they're before the pictures. Have a great time with us here at The Great Outdoors!

Comment: Not an answer as I do not have personal experience with mounting bindings, but this is definitely wrong. If this was done by a professional, bring it back and request a replacement. This will at the very least affect the skiing (more resistance) and probably also the durability. Just imagine catching a rock at one of these points: It will hit the screw easily and thus put a huge strain on the material around.

Comment: OUCH , yes it will effect durability.   Demand new skis or a refund.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I used to do some work as a ski technician many years ago, and yes, definitely this is not correct. You should not be able to see the screws from the underside.

Take them back for a replacement, they are potentially dangerous and unlikely to last for as long as they could be expected to.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The retailer is sending me a replacement. cheers